# Entire Application in Django shuts down with single error

Tags: python, django

I am new to Python and django , I worked on C# and php as developer earlier. 
My problem here is Entire Application in Django shuts down with single error.

for example i start my website with "python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000" 
example:-- i have two pages home and register
1) if i make error in register page code(register.py) , It shuts down home page too. Is there a way to prevent that as in php and C# in both one page do not effect other.
2) how to work in django with team one errors full team hangs.

3) How to work with live working websites things may become too risky.

also i am not able to find article related to this.
kindly help

Comment: 1) I think you are using one file for one view ie for register, register.py and for home, home.py or something else, If you use views in single views.py, error won't effect unless that view is called.

Comment: i have made separate view  in a view folder register.py is different from home.py
but both are under one folder named "view" folder

Comment: When Django loads the URL patterns, the views are imported, so you can't prevent a bug in one file crashing the server. You should develop on separate machines so that you can't break each others dev environments. Then, write unit tests for all your views, so that you don't deploy broken code.